# Pitest (PIT Mutation Testing) exception with local dynamodb

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, dynamo-local, pitest

I'm recieving the following pi-test exception when I have local dynamoDB lib files in my java project with a gradle build. Seems pi-test tries to open the lib file. Could not find a way to exclude lib files from pi-test either.

`:pitest
Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.util.PitError: error in opening zip file (/Users/user1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.almworks.sqlite4java/libsqlite4java-linux-i386/1.0.392/b193c62571061e68bddeaf8ee7d3a8569b945ea6/libsqlite4java-linux-i386-1.0.392.so)`

How can I solve this issue and have the mutation test on the gradle project?

Answer (score 0):

This issue supposed to be fixed in the PI-test Gradle plugin v 1.1.11
(issue open: https://github.com/szpak/gradle-pitest-plugin/issues/52)